# Angular - loop over form elements that are in a child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a form in a directive template:

```
<form class="form-dark dotted-border-top" name="vmParms.frmTLParms">
    <parm parameter="parm" ng-repeat="parm in vmParms.truckloadParms"></parm>
</form>
```

and the child directive `parm` has a bunch of `input` elements on it and DOES NOT have it's own controller.

```
<div>                               
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="parameter.workValue" ng-required="true" />
</div>
```

I am trying to loop over every element that is on this form in my controller:

```
console.log(vmParms.frmTLParms);

angular.forEach(vmParms.frmTLParms, function(value, key) {
    // Do something with (value, key)
});
```

but the output from the console log is `undefined`

Any idea on how I can loop over all these form elements (I need to get information about $pristine which is why I need the form elements, not just the parameter objects)?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that parameter  is two way data binding ("parameter" : "=" in the directive)

try this:

```
angular.forEach(vmParms.truckloadParms, function(value, key) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the issue:

This form was embedded in another `<form>` earlier in the DOM. HTML5 does not natively do nested forms. Switching the `<form>` tag to `<ng-form>` solved my problem.

Thanks for the assistance @avim101!